# How to order String based on few numeric characters

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

Peace be upon you :)

Say I have:

```
 ----------------------------
| Hellohowruimfindandu|  30  |
 ----------------------------
| asdjflkdsjfklajlkjlk|  25  |
 ----------------------------
| sdf8sd8f97asjdkfjldl|  33  |
 ----------------------------
| sdfajsdfklajsdlfkajd|  18  |
 ----------------------------
| dfjalsjfdaldjflsdjfl|  0   |
 ----------------------------
| Hellohowruimfindandu|  15  |
 ----------------------------
| aasdklfjaklsdjaksjdf|  13  |
 ----------------------------
| jdsflkajsdflasjdfljl|  19  |
```

In actual code it's like:

```
String[] Str = new String[20];
Str[0] = "Hellohowruimfindandu"+"\u0003"+"30";
Str[1] = "asdjflkdsjfklajlkjlk"+"\u0003"+"25";
// And so on
```

Now I want to sort this array based on it's numeric value. say:

```
 ----------------------------
| dfjalsjfdaldjflsdjfl|  0   |
 ----------------------------
| aasdklfjaklsdjaksjdf|  13  |
 ----------------------------
| Hellohowruimfindandu|  15  |
```

And so on;

Comment: What stopping you to do that ?

Comment: Yeah. Plus variable names should not start with an uppercase letter. Follow the Java Naming Conventions and replace `Str` by `str`.

Comment: `Arrays.sort(Str, Comparator.comparingInt(s -> Integer.parseInt(s.substring(21))));`

Comment: @ScaryWombat Yeah. Trying to learn from posted answers ;)

Comment: @ Suresh Atta : me too

Comment: You can accept the answer if it helped you!

Answer (score 1):

For such type of application, more efficient way is make a class having two attributes: `String` and an `Integer`. Now make a list of this class objects. You can sort this list based on String (lexicographic) or Integer using `Comparator` class.

For example:

You class should be:

```
public class MyClass{
    String s;
    int value;

    MyClass(String str, int v){
        s = str;
        value = v;
    }
}
```

You can make list of this class as following:

```
ArrayList<MyClass> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(new MyClass("str1", val1));
list.add(new MyClass("str2", val2));
            ...
```

And sort as following:

```
Collections.sort(list, (a, b) -> a.value < b.value ? -1 : a.value == b.value ? 0 : 1);
```

Above code will only work on Java8, as it is using lambda expressions. See below code without lambda expression.

```
Collections.sort(list,new Comparator<MyClass>(){
   @Override
   public int compare(final MyClass a,MyClass b) {
     //TODO return 1 if b should be before a
     //     return -1 if a should be before b
     //     return 0 otherwise
    }
});
```

Or as suggested by @StutiRastogi if you don't want to change your structure, you've to parse integers, then sort them with keeping track of old and new indexes and then again you've to sort String according to indexes.

Comment: While true, This pushes to change all the existing code structure. Rather I prefer splitting and compare in sort method itself. +1 for Recommended solution.

Comment: yeah but without changing the structure, splitting will be inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

Get the last two characters of every String element (if you know it's only 2 digit numbers), parse them as integers, sort them and store the index values and then display your strings using that index ordering. This is an outline of the approach, without actual code so you can give it a shot.

If you can make changes to the way the array is stored, may I suggest using a class with a String and integer as the members. That way, you can operate on them separately as needed and concatenate them, when required. Using the object-oriented approach, may make your life a lot easier.